Why did my touchpad randomly stop working?
While i was using my computer, the touchpad randomly stopped working, clicks worked, and i had to plug in an external mouse. the computer model i have is a hp stream model 14-cb172wm. the ubuntu version im on is ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

Recently, my after-reboot default touchpad settings changed. So after each reboot, I had to enable tap to click. Do you know the way to enable/disable the touchpad through your device hardware switch settings? This is usually like an fn key button or like for example, my external keyboard with touchpad uses the fn+Left-click combo. So I would have to press fn+Left-click after a reboot. It seem whatever was causing this has fixed itself for me, however, and after the most recent reboot, didn't have to enable tap to click.

Also and to help diagnose the issue, there are a few things you can look at. First, for Wayland users (Ubuntu default), install libinput-tools: sudo apt update and sudo apt install libinput-tools and then run sudo libinput list-devices and then use libinput --help for more options. The settings listed may help people diagnose the issue so if you could please edit your question to include the output for that touchpad device, that would be helpful.
